# List view - any way to scroll horizontally?

Tags: swiftui

I have a list that loads from a parsed CSV file built using SwiftUI and I can't seem to find a way to scroll the list horizontally.

```
List {
    // Read each row of the array and return it as arrayRow
    ForEach(arrayToUpload, id: \.self) { arrayRow in
        HStack {
            // Read each column of the array (Requires the count of the number of columns from the parsed CSV file - itemsInArray)
            ForEach(0..<self.itemsInArray) { itemNumber in
                Text(arrayRow[itemNumber])
                    .fixedSize()
                    .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
.frame(minWidth: 1125, maxWidth: 1125, minHeight: 300, maxHeight: 300)
.border(Color.black)
```

The list renders how I would like but I'm just stuck on this one point.

[Preview Image Of Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOTNm.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**;
**iOS 13.4**

You should use an ScrollView as Vyacheslav Pukhanov suggested but in your case the scrollView size does not get updated after the async call data arrive. So you have 2 options:

1. Provide a default value or an alternative view.
2. Provide a fixed size to the HStack inside of the ForeEach. (I used this one)

I faced the same problem laying out an horizontal grid of two columns. Here's my solution

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReviewGrid: View {
    @ObservedObject private var reviewListViewModel: ReviewListViewModel

init(movieId: Int) {
    reviewListViewModel = ReviewListViewModel(movieId: movieId)
    //ReviewListViewModel will request all reviews for the given movie id
}

var body: some View {
    let chunkedReviews = reviewListViewModel.reviews.chunked(into: 2)
    // After the API call arrive chunkedReviews will get somethig like this => [[review1, review2],[review3, review4],[review5, review6],[review7, review8],[review9]]
    return ScrollView (.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<chunkedReviews.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(chunkedReviews[index], id: \.id) { review in
                            Text("*\(review.body)*").padding().font(.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

}

This is a dummy example don't expect a fancy view ;)

[image]

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a horizontal [`ScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview) instead of the List for this purpose.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    VStack {
        ForEach(arrayToUpload, id: \.self) { arrayRow in
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<self.itemsInArray) { itemNumber in
                    Text(arrayRow[itemNumber])
                        .fixedSize()
                        .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - the data does now scroll horizontally but I now have a new problem with it - the data does not display on the first load. If I switch tabs and come back the data does show. Is there anyway I can force refresh a ScrollView?